# @Input decorator returning undefined in child class

Tags: javascript, angular, undefined, decorator

I have two Components StudentsComponent and UnderGradsComponent. In the students component, I created a method to get me the names of students who are "undergrads" in a list. Then im sending this list ot the undergrads component. However, I am always getting that list as undefined inside the undergrads component.

Here is the code for my StudentsComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-students",
  templateUrl: "./students.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./students.component.css"]
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {
  students = [
    { name: "Marwa", level: "undergrad" },
    { name: "Heba", level: "undergrad" },
    { name: "Amal", level: "postgrad" }
  ];

  public undergradsList = this.undergrads();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.undergrads();
    console.log(this.undergrads);
  }
  undergrads() {
    var Arrayres = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
      if (this.students[i].level === "undergrad") {
        Arrayres.push(this.students[i].name);
      }
    }
    console.log(Arrayres);
    return Arrayres;
  }
}
```

Here is the html for the StudentsComponent

```
<app-under-grads *ngIf="undergradsList" [studentList]="undergradsList">
</app-under-grads>
```

Here is the code for the UndergradsComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-under-grads",
  templateUrl: "./under-grads.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./under-grads.component.css"]
})
export class UnderGradsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public studentList;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.studentList);
  }
}
```

Finally here is the code for my HTML UnderGradsCompoenent

```
<h2>UnderGrads</h2>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let x of studentList">{{ x }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide more details, such as the actual content of `under-grads.component.html`?

Comment: @abos i edited my question

Comment: I created a stackblitz and could not reproduce this issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owhv9c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstudent.component.ts

Comment: @ABOS Is there a problem with my *ngFor? i feel like it is causing the problem

Comment: @abos also, why are you using the class tag for the student not the undergrad in the app.compoenent.html

Comment: I used your code and it seemed to be working ... perhaps you can double check your original code.

Comment: @ Marwa, you are using student class as parent, and under-grads as child since under-grads is embed in student's template .

Comment: I just figured out the problem I was using the undergrad component selector to render rather than using the student component